# Pandas, concentrate values to list in first cell of each column in first row

Tags: pandas

I need to concentrate values to list in first cell of each column in first row

My data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':['one','one','two'],
    'B':[2,np.nan,2],
    'C':['main','main','main']
})
print(df)
     A    B     C
0  one  2.0  main
1  one  NaN  main
2  two  2.0  main
```

expected output:

```
    A              B           C
0  one,one,two  2.0,2.0  main,main,main
```

for one column, its not problem because I can use `tolist()` but in ths case i've tried to use :

`df=df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().values.tolist()), axis=1)`

from this topic:

[Concatenate cells into a string with separator pandas python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983946/concatenate-cells-into-a-string-with-separator-pandas-python)
but in there , it's not a list but a string, anyway I am receiving : 
`TypeError: ('sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found', 'occurred at index 0')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the column to string and join:

```
df.agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)))
```

Output:

```
A       one,one,two
B           2.0,2.0
C    main,main,main
dtype: object
```

To get a dataframe, you can chain that with `.to_frame().T`:

```
df.agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str))).to_frame().T
```

gives you

```
              A        B               C
0  one,one,two  2.0,2.0  main,main,main
```

Comment: hi, i need it in form like in "expected output" with A,B,C columns