# Join columns which were mangled on import

Tags: python, pandas, csv

When using `pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', delimiter=';')` on a csv which duplicated column names, pandas mangles the duplicated columns with `.1`, `.2`, `.#` *(# is the number of the duplicated column)*

My example csv looks like this:

| data1 | data2 | A | B | B | C | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | NaN | text1 | text2 | text3 | text4 | text5 |
| def | 456 | text2 | text4 | text3 | text5 | text1 |

```
Data1;Data2;A;B;B;C;C
abc;;text1;text2;text3;text4;text5
def;456;text2;text4;text3;text5;text1
```

After import to dataframe, the duplicated columns get mangled:

[image: mangled_columns]

This output is expected.

But I wish to combine these duplicated columns and their rows as comma-seperated strings.

So the desired output would look like:
*(order of columns is not important)*

| data1 | data2 | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 123 | text1 | text2,text3 | text4,text5 |
| def | 456 | text2 | text4,text3 | text5,text1 |

**How can I achieve that with pandas in python?**

I found the following question when searching for the problem:

[Concatenate cells into a string with separator pandas python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983946/concatenate-cells-into-a-string-with-separator-pandas-python)

But I don't know how to apply the answer from that question to only those columns which are mangled.

Comment: I've adjusted the original question to include numbers in the given dataset. The duplicated columns can always be seen as strings, since they'll end up as strings eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename your columns, stack, join, unstack:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', sep=';')

# remove the '.x' in columns
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.split('.')[0])

# reshaping
(df.set_index(['Data1', 'Data2']) # set those columns aside
   .stack()                       # columns to rows
   .groupby(level=[0,1,2])        # group by all
   .apply(','.join)               # join duplicates
   .unstack()                     # A/B/C back to columns
)
```

output:

```
                 A            B            C
Data1 Data2                                 
abc   def    text1  text2,text3  text4,text5
asd   fgh    text2  text4,text3  text5,text1
```

Comment: That looks to be working, could you explain what you're doing here?

Comment: @HackXIt I commented the code, let me know if you have questions

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Is there a way to set aside columns which aren't duplicated?  Inserting each column manually that isn't duplicated seems cumbersome with larger datasets.

Comment: Is the set_index even necessary? Column A isn't duplicated and left untouched I just noticed.

Comment: By the way, if there's more than 3 rows, using `groupby(level=list(range(len(df.index))))` instead works more generically. There might be a more elegant way to do this though.

Comment: Your solution drops rows with NaN values. Is there a way to consider `NaN` and numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390645/python-pandas-merge-samed-name-columns-in-a-dataframe):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'./example.csv', delimiter=';')

def sjoin(x): 
    return ';'.join(x[x.notnull()].astype(str))

df = df.groupby(lambda col: col.split('.')[0], axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.apply(sjoin, axis=1))
```

Which results in:

```
       A            B            C Data1 Data2
0  text1  text2;text3  text4;text5   abc   def
1  text2  text4;text3  text5;text1   asd   fgh
```

Comment: I thought of that for a moment, but this involves a loop within a loop, probably not efficient on large datasets

Comment: Indeed, the decision on which method to use is dependent on the size of the dataset & how much you need to prioritize efficiency.

Comment: For those interested, this method is 300 times slower than @mozway for the example csv given repeated for 60,000 rows

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, grouping the mangled columns with a regular expression:

```
# (.*?): capture the original column name at the beginning of the string
# potentially followed by a dot and at least one digit
shared_groupname = r"(.*?)(?:\.\d+)?$"
```

Let's see that in action:

```
>>> df.columns.str.extract(shared_groupname) 
       0
0  Data1
1  Data2
2      A
3      B
4      B
5      C
6      C
```

Then groupby this original column name, and apply the join:

```
grouped = df.groupby(df.columns.str.extract(shared_groupname, expand=False), axis=1)

res = grouped.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().astype(str).apply(', '.join, axis=1))
```

Comment: This throws `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found` if the dataset contains something else than strings. _(floats for example)_

Works for string-only datasets though.

Comment: Ah. That's fixed with an additional `.dropna().astype(str)` in the apply, from the answer you cite above.

Comment: I've adjusted the original question to include numbers.

Comment: I'm getting `ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type Series` when applied in the larger dataset. I'm unsure where this comes from.